# How to use VLOOKUP to return repeating lookup values?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, vlookup

I will be using a VLOOKUP formula countless times and I am stumped on how to use VLOOKUP to return repeating values using different searches

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvoNT.jpg)

Column A has lots of random zipcodes, and Column E has 5 different regions.

What VLOOKUP formula to put on B2 which I can drag down?

I tried =VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$436,2,false) but it's just giving me N/A

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: For Column B to show which region (Column E) the zipcode in column C is in.

Comment: If the target zipcode is in column C as you state in your comment, why is the vlookup you show using cell A2 as the target?

Comment: Sorry, the target zipcode would be Column A and then Column D would be the reference to which region they are in. The INDEX formula below fixed it. 

Can't it be done just by using VLOOKUP?

Comment: Can you provide a shorter table including desired results pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in B2 (do not drag down):

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; D:E; 2; 0)))
```

---

formatting fix:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&""; D:E&""; 2; 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's just giving me a blank cell. Anything I'm missing on the original VLOOKUP formula?

Comment: I think this need arrayformula.

Comment: @Harun24HR I think cell A2 should be C2... based on the comment from the OP above.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SzoEVPnK27JDXJGGQSQ6t3GHKKlZPyH4sQORuQK6T24/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formatting fix did it. Much appreciated, chief. Cheers!

Comment: Range can come from a different sheet, right? 

=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&""; 'SHEET NAME'!D:E&""; 2; 0)))

Comment: @DennieLesterQuiambao yes indeed